# Memory heap corruption and GFlags/windbg

Tags: c++, windbg

I have an application wich produce memory heap exception (corruption).

On the web I have found this kind of sentence :

> "GFlags.exe: A heap debug program. Using GFlags, you can establish
>   standard, /full, or /dlls heap options that will force the operating
>   system to generate access violations and corruption errors when your
>   program overwrites heap memory. "

But concretely how can I with GFlags or Windbg find the line in my source code which causes the bug?

Is there any good/synthetic paper on the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GFlags` can cause the heap manager in Windows to behave differently to aid debugging of heap problems.

When used with `/full` option your program will “crash” due to an access violation if you access an allocated buffer past its length.

(Without GFlags `/full`, the program may continue and the problem appear much later) 
You can utilize just in time debugging with VS or WinDbg or collect a crash dump.

The debugger should now point to the error (Instruction Pointer) 
and hopefully you will find the statement in your source that caused the bug.

Be aware that the `/full` option causes the program to use much more memory and can therefore only be used on relatively small programs.
If the `/full` option doesn’t cause a “crash” try also with  `/full /backwards`.

Comment: you see IP via !analyse -v for instance ?

Comment: Yes with source and .prd available you may also see a sniplet of the source. But uf the error is caused by a illegal parameter to f.eks memcpy you must walk the stack back to your code.